# How to store and fetch data from hash tables - javascript

Tags: javascript, file-io, hashmap

I couldn't find anything on javascript but this might be clarified very quickly.  I am working on a website where I have to retrieve data via http requests from a server.  Because I need to make several requests and the data is constant what I want to do is make table with keys and values -> store those values in a file -> and then be able to retrieve those values.  That way I have to read one file as apposed to fetching data via 30 http requests

General Idea :

```
Given: spell id = number (Ex. 45)
Output: name of spell = string (Ex. fire...)

Use this output to then fetch the url of the image of the spell (containing the spell name)
```

---

EDIT

Code :

```
// When I fetch the file i use (json data)
    function getChampionImage(id) {
                    var champUrl = "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/na/v1.2/champion/" +id +"/?api_key=....."
                    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlHttp.open( "GET", champUrl, false );
                    xmlHttp.send( null );
                    var jsonText = xmlHttp.responseText;
                    var champData = JSON.parse(jsonText);
                    var champName = champData.key;
                    return "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/" + versionNum + "/img/champion/"+champName+".png";


                }
```

Comment: if you post your file loading code, i'll show you how to integrate a cache, it's pretty simple.

Comment: I added the code where I fetch the json and then get the data to use in the url.  Don't know if this is what you are talking about or not

Comment: A javascript object is a hashtable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need to do is tack the response onto an object, keyed by input.
this is especially simple in sync IO because you don't have to worry about callback scope.

Since functions are objects in JS, you can just use the procedure itself as a namespace, which plays well with methods because you don't need an outside variable:

```
// When I fetch the file i use (json data)
    function getChampionImage(id) {
                    var cached=getChampionImage["_"+id];
                    if(cached) return cached;
                    var champUrl = "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/na/v1.2/champion/" +id +"/?api_key=....."
                    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlHttp.open( "GET", champUrl, false );
                    xmlHttp.send( null );
                    var jsonText = xmlHttp.responseText;
                    var champData = JSON.parse(jsonText);
                    var champName = champData.key;
                    return getChampionImage["_"+id]="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/" + versionNum + "/img/champion/"+champName+".png";

                }
```

EDIT: to persist the url data between page visits, use localStorage as the hash object:

```
function getChampionImage(id) {
                var cached=localStorage["_"+id];
                if(cached) return cached;
                var champUrl = "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/na/v1.2/champion/" +id +"/?api_key=....."
                xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlHttp.open( "GET", champUrl, false );
                xmlHttp.send( null );
                var jsonText = xmlHttp.responseText;
                var champData = JSON.parse(jsonText);
                var champName = champData.key;
                return localStorage["_"+id]="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/" + versionNum + "/img/champion/"+champName+".png";


            }
```

note that with localStorage, you'll have to self-expire the cache if you make changes.

Comment: But when I reload the page will the cache remain?  I feel as though if I reload the page the cache would be wiped clean right? Edit - because if i find a champ on one client - I want it to be in the cache of the client that accesses the website after them

Comment: i didn't notice a part about persistence, but that's easy too, i'll show you in an edit

Comment: ok.  Yes if i can just get it to remain in cache.  I have to go but Ill be back in a hour.  you can just edit response.  gracias

Comment: What do you mean by self-expire? - sry this is a bad question - does this mean edit the cache for the time being
Also...is this localStorage variable already made in html automatically?

Comment: yes, localStorage comes with the browser, virtually all of them. my point was that once it's cached in this system, it will never be fetched again, so if you want to update the data, you'll have to manually delete the localStorage key, or change the url by appending a random query string parameter, so it's missed by the cache. if the data behind a given URL never changes anyway, then disregard the whole warning.

Comment: Nvm.  You are the best.  Made my program lightning speed.

Comment: I understand now.  I don't think the data will change but i can store the version number and compare them to see if i need to change anything.  thank you

Comment: there is also one option in-between permanent localStroage and page-temporary objects: sessionStorage, which works like localStorage, except it's wiped when the tab closes. longer than refresh, short than forever.